# Excel SheetSelectionChange event example needed

Tags: windows, excel, visual-c++, com

I have a problem I'm trying to solve involving interfaceing a C++ program with Excel (an import interface, specifically). The  SheetSelectionChange sounds like it will get me most of the way to where I need to be, but I can't find any good documentation or examples on registering the event, using its Range parameter when it's fired, and unregistering when done. My code currently doesn't use the COM wrapper classes; it issues QueryInterface calls to pick up pointers to the interfaces in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the Excel events interface, and then advise on the Excel connection point. Look at [Office Automation Using VC++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776/), more specifically point 7. You can also look at [Handle Events for Excel using Visual C++.Net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309301)